Capacitor Android - Floating Keyboard
Im building a fullscreen android app using Capacitor and React JS. However I think in a typical fullscreen app in android, the keyboard will be floating by default as presented in apps like Fun Run or Mobile Legends. Is there a way for me to programmatically to make the keyboard not floating by default?
